# Eclipse Helios - Problem Adding PHP Executable

Tags: php, eclipse, mamp, eclipse-pdt

I just installed Eclipse Helios (`zend-eclipse-php-helios-macosx-cocoa-x86.tar.gz`) on my Mac (OS X v. 10.5.8).
When I try to add a PHP executable (`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php`), I get the following message:

```
Selected location doesn't refer to a valid PHP executable
```

and Eclipse won't allow me to add this executable- which *is* a valid PHP executable.
See ...

```
[23:34 44]
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php -v
PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2010 16:45:34) Copyright (c) 1997-2010 
The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 
Zend Technologies
with XCache v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2009, by mOo
with Xdebug v2.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2009, by Derick Rethans
```

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Rylie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this similar to [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&th=172789) where PDT on Helios lacks a direct compatibility with PHP5.3?

A possible workaround was presented in [bug 28157 "Unable to add PHP executable"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281578#c6), with a wrapper around `php`.

Comment: Thanks. I did read that thread, but doesn't seem right because the previous Eclipse version (Galileo) did support PHP 5.3. In fact, it [Galileo] accepted the exact same PHP executable that I'm now trying to add to Helios (with not much luck). If that thread is correct, then Helios regressed, which I hope is not the case.

Comment: @Rylie: I don't think the compatibility issue was the real problem here. I was more interested in the wrapper around the php executable prposed in the bug 28157. I haven't tested it, but maybe that could help.